# When does linear combination of real-rooted entire functions of genus 0 or 1 remain real-rooted?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

In our search of a family of entire functions to approximate Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function, we encounter the following family of functions:

$$f_m(z,n,b)=\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k u_k(z,n,b)\tag{1}$$

where $b>0$,$n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$u_k(z,n,b)=g_k(z,n,b)+\overline{g_k(\overline{z},n,b)}\tag{2}$$
$$g_k(z,n,b)=c_k(n) \frac{\sin\left(b(z-i(k+1/4))\right)}{b(z-i(k+1/4))}\tag{3}$$

$$c_k(n)=\pi^k a_k H_{n,-2k}\tag{4}$$
$$a_k=\frac{2k+1}{(k-1)!},k\in\mathbb{N}\tag{5}$$
And $H_{n,m}$ is the Harmonic number of order $m$,
$$H_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-m}.\tag{6}$$

Our goal is to prove that

***Proposition 1*** $f_m(z,n,b)$ as a function of z, has only real zeros.

One way we are trying to achieve this goal is to apply a theorem by Polya:

***Theorem 2*** (Polya [1]):

Assume (1) $G(z)$ is an entire function of genus 0 or 1 and all the zeros of $G(z)$ are in the half plane of $Im(z)>0$, i.e., $G(z)$ belongs to Hermite-Biehler class of entire functions;

(2)
$$h(z)=\frac{G(z)}{\quad\overline{G(\overline{z})}\quad},|h(z)|<1,\qquad Im(z)>0\tag{6}$$
Then the function $G(z)+\overline{G(\overline{z})}$ has only real zeros.

We can readily show that $b(z-ia)^{-1}\sin(b(z-ia))$ with $a,b>0$ has the same properties as $G(z)$ in Theorem 1 has. Thus $u_k(z,n,b)$,$k\in\mathbb{N}$ are real-rooted.

Thus for any $n,m\in\mathbb{N},b>0$, $f_m(z,n,b)$ is a linear combination of real rooted entire function of genus 0. In addition, numerical results shows that sequence $c_k$ is log-concave (this is something we think that can be proved).

Any thoughts, suggestions, references on how to prove ***Proposition 1*** are welcome.

[1] George Polya, Bemerkunguber die Integraldarstellung der Riemannsche ξ-Funktion, Acta Math. 48 (1926), 305–317

Comment: @MiceElf. thanks for the suggestion. Which tags would you suggest?

Comment: @MiceElf: Thanks a lot for the editing and adding the tags. Best

Comment: An observation: If $z=2\pi $ then $z^{-1}\sin (z)=\frac{\sin(2\pi)}{2\pi}=0$ so the function $z^{-1}\sin(z)$ has a zero in $Im(z)=0$. In that case, does theorem 2 still apply?

Comment: what is your $G(z)$, $z^{-1}\sin z$ or $(z-2i)^{-1}\sin(z-2i)$?

Comment: I think it's a typo, but, in what you wrote, actually $G(z)=(b(z+ia))^{-1}\sin (b(z+ia))$ with $a,b>0$ so $z=\frac{2\pi}{b}-ia$ is a root of $G(z)$

Comment: $G(z)=(b(z-ia))^{-1}\sin (b(z-ia))$ with $a,b>0$.

Comment: It's a typo then, because equation (3) in the question mentions $(z+ia)$ with $a=k(1+1/4)$.

Comment: you are right. I will change it then. thanks

Comment: We post a partial answer to this question at [mathoverflow site](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223798/is-the-difference-of-these-two-real-rooted-functions-real-rooted)